# Change options value programmatically using Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I have a options binding with knockout that looks like this:

```
<select id="ddlProducts" data-bind="options: ShowProducts, optionsText: 'pruductskuname', optionsCaption: 'Choose a product...', value: currentproduct"></select>
```

I have an ajax call that validates a serial number and return's a product name. I want to change the Selected Option to the return product. The return from my ajax call is the product name: pruductskuname

Is there a way to set the selected option based on my return?

For example if the return if my Return == ProductA I want to find in my Options ProductA and set the value to ProductA.

Here is my VM:

```
    /* Data View Model */
    var myDataViewModel = {
        products: ko.observableArray(),
        viewserialized: ko.observable(1),
        currentordernumer: ko.observable(),
        currentserialqty: ko.observable(),
        currentproduct: ko.observable(),
        dataitems: ko.observableArray()
    };
```

and here is my ajax call that gets the return message:

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "ServiceURL",
                data: { Serial: ko.toJS(myDataViewModel.currentserialqty) },
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "JSON",
                timeout: 10000,
                success: function (Result) {
                   /*SET OPTION BINDING HERE BASED ON Result.d */
                    alert(Result.d);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status) {
                    alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there are two ways of doing this, one would be to set the optionsValue to the pruductskuname like so:

```
 <select id="ddlProducts" data-bind="options: ShowProducts, optionsText: 'pruductskuname', optionsCaption: 'Choose a product...', value: currentproduct", optionsValue: 'pruductskuname'></select>
```

This will make currentproduct be equal to the name of the product, so all you would have to do in your success callback is myDataViewModel.currentproduct(Result.d);

If you don't do that you could

```
  myDataViewModel.currentproduct(ko.utils.arrayFirst(myDataViewModel.products(), function (item)
    {
        return item.pruductskuname() === Result.d;  //note the ()
    })
```

which will search for the item with that name and set it to the current product.

Comment: There was an error in the code: `return item.pruductskuname() === Result.d;` should chage to `return item.pruductskuname === Result.d;` Tthen it works. Thanks a Million

Comment: Oh ok I assumed the objects in your array have observable properties, how are you populating your array?

Comment: It does have observable properties, I populate it this way: Here is my ajax success method `success: function (Result) {
                for (var i = 0; i < Result.d.length; i++) {
                    element = Result.d[i];
                    myDataViewModel.products.push({ productskuid: element.ProductSKUID, pruductskuname: element.ProductSKUName, productskurequiresvalidation: element.ProductSKURequiresValidation });
                }
            },`

Comment: They aren't actually observable properties in the array. change productskuid: element.ProductSKUID, pruductskuname: element.ProductSKUName, productskurequiresvalidation: element.ProductSKURequiresValidation to productskuid: ko.observable(element.ProductSKUID), pruductskuname: ko.observable(element.ProductSKUName), productskurequiresvalidation: ko.observable(element.ProductSKURequiresValidation) and they will now be observable.

Comment: what you are doing there is pushing a simple javascript object into the observable array. This means that every time a new item is pushed into the array or something is removed or something is moved around it will publish to all subscribers that a change has been made, however it will not publish to subscribers once the name has been changed or the id, or the requires validation.

Comment: Oh ok, did not know that, luckily the Array objects won't change. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: no worries, it took me a while to release that in knockout, but once you do it becomes a very powerful tool. A very simple test would be to change the name of one of the items and realise the list doesn't update.